# Remove NSUserDefaults after sandboxes mac app uninstall

Tags: macos, uninstallation

I have a sandboxed app which is installed from Mac AppStore.

It writes to `NSUserDefaults`. I was expecting `NSUserDefaults` to go away when the app is deleted (the same way how it happens for iOS sandboxes apps).

However, `NSUserDefaults` are left lingering behind. As result, if a user reinstall the app, he/she still can access the same things which was in NSDefaults (in my case, which is negative side effect).

I wonder whether there is a way (specifically for AppStore sandboxed apps) to delete `NSUserDefaults` on uninstall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since macOS, in general, allows you to delete applications simply by dragging them to the Trash rather than making you run an uninstaller, there's no way to force tasks such as deletion of user defaults to be run on uninstall.

I, personally, consider this to be a feature, not a bug; if I, as a user, have an application become corrupted and need to uninstall and reinstall it, that shouldn't force me to have to reset all my data associated with that application in the process. But YMMV.

If this is really a problem, you could do something like store your application's value for either `NSURLContentModificationDateKey` or `NSURLAddedToDirectoryDateKey` in the user defaults, and on application launch, test whether that matches. If it doesn't, the app's likely been reinstalled, and you could offer to nuke the defaults data. I'd really suggest putting up a dialog box asking the user before doing this, though, since having one's data destroyed without warning is rather un-Mac-like and contrary to what many of your users will expect (and also because otherwise, you'll nuke their data every time they update the app to a later version).

Comment: Interesting idea about ContentModificationDate. Thanks. I agree that it could be treated as a feature for non AppStore apps. However, AppStore apps are different (much closer to iOS).

Comment: @VictorRonin Mac App Store apps are still Mac apps, and should still behave like Mac apps. If your app does not, you *will* aggravate some of your users.